# Do black holes emit enough heat to heat a planet?

Tags: exoplanet, heat, black-hole

Under what circumstances can a blackhole emit enough heat to allow life on an orbiting planet?

Comment: If enough interstellar gas falls in. But the radiation happens mostly in the gamma spectrum, so don't expect a warn sunshine. The gamma energy which can keep an Earth-like planet warm, would cause deadly radiation damage in minutes in a human.

Comment: This is an interesting question but it is off-topic here in Space Exploration SE. But don't worry, it is probably on-topic in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) and there is a chance that it might be migrated to that site. It can be a little confusing which site to ask on at first, but you'll get used to it. There are [almost 200 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) to choose from!

Comment: **update:** probably your question is already answered there! See answers to [Life planets orbiting black-holes. Can/Do they really exist?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10373/7982) and also [Is it safer to be near a star or a black hole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/3683/7982) and perhaps [A star a black hole and planets around them](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12662/7982)